# node sequelize - select with null value

Tags: sql, node.js, sequelize.js, where-clause

```
var where = {
  [Op.or]:
      [
          { status: { [Op.ne]: 'disable' } },
          { status: { [Op.eq]: null } }
      ],
}

db.diagnostic.findAll({ where: where }).then(resp => {
  res.send(resp)
})
```

This above code is working
but,

```
var where = {
  status: { [Op.ne]: 'disable' } // I want use only this code instead of `or`
}

db.diagnostic.findAll({ where: where }).then(resp => {
  res.send(resp)
})
```

I want to use only `status: { [Op.ne]: 'disable' }`

Comment: And what goes wrong? In the second case you'll get in SQL something like: (title ilike '%seach_value%' OR ...) AND status <> 'disable'. Isn't it what you want to achieve?

Comment: I didn't understand what exactly you want to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model: diagnostic.js

```
...
    status: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      defaultValue: "enable", // <-  default value will solve my problem
    }
...
```